# Find item from generic list

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

I have a problem in fetching the record from a generic list. I have created a common function from where i want to get the records from any type of class. Below is sample code:-

```
public void Test<T>(List<T> rEntity) where T : class
{
    object id = 1;
    var result = rEntity.Where(x => x.id == id);
}
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you expect `Test<Type>()` to do? Or `Test<StringBuilder>()`? It seems to me like your `T` requires a lot more in the way of constraints...

Comment: This code should not even compile, since T being a class does not mean that T is a collection of objects that has a property called id.

Comment: Hi Jon, 'T' is a Generic class name which we will pass while calling the above method. Thanks

Comment: It's really not clear what you are doing here. Why aren't you just using `list.Where(...)`?

Comment: you most define a basic class that have id property and your T most be inherit from that basic class, in posted code you most have compiler error

Comment: Just for update, we are calling this function as Test<t_usertable>(rEntity); where t_usertable is a class defined in code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With method like that a usual question for compiler is 'what is T' ?
If it's just a class it could be anything even a `StringBuilder` as Jon has mentioned and there is no guarantee that it has a property 'Id'. So it won't even compile the way it is right now.

To make it work we have two options :

A) Change the method and let compiler know what type to expect

B) Use reflection and use run-time operations (better avoid this when possible but may come handy when working with 3rd party libraries).

A - Interface solution :

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
   int Id {get; set;}
}

public void Test<T>(List<T> rEntity) where T : IMyInterface
{
    object id = 1;
    var result = rEntity.Where(x => x.id == id);
}
```

B - Reflection solution:

```
public void Test<T>(List<T> rEntity)
{
    var idProp = typeof(T).GetProperty("Id");
    if(idProp != null)
    {
       object id = 1;
       var result = rEntity.Where(x => idProp.GetValue(x).Equals(id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fabjan, You saved my lot of time. Reflection solution is working for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You most define a basic class that have id property and your T most be inherit from that basic class.

```
public class BaseClass{
public object ID;
}
```

and you can change your function like this:

```
public void Test<T>(List<T> rEntity) where T : BaseClass
{
    object id = 1;
    var result = rEntity.Where(x => x.id == id);
}
```