# Get property value from a collection object

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have 2 class with the following definitions:

```
public class Calculation
{
    public int Id;
    public ICollection<CalculationDetails> CalculationDetails;
}

public class CalculationDetails
{
    public int Id;
    public decimal? Rate;
    public decimal? Amount;
    public int ChargeId;
    public string Category;
    public int UnitId;
}
```

I want a generic extension method for ICollection that will take the name of the property, calculationId and category and will return the the value of the appropriate property after filtering the list.
Something like this:

```
public static T GetCalculationDetailsValue(this ICollection<CalculationDetails> freightCalculationDetails, string propertyName, int calculationId, string category)
{
    // using reflection or any suitable method returns the value as per the specified property name 
    // in the parameter.
}
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366996/find-item-from-generic-list) example.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `propertyName` doesn't have to be a string, you can use a lambda expression to extract the right field instead. C# is strongly typed, so this is the best solution that I can see if you want to have properties in PriceCalculationDetails to be of different types.

```
    public static T GetTheThing<T>(this ICollection<CalculationDetails> calculationDetails, Func<CalculationDetails, T> propertyExtractor, int calculationId, string category)
    {
        var matchingCalculationDetails = calculationDetails.First();    // Insert your preferred logic to find the right one here.

        return propertyExtractor(matchingCalculationDetails);
    }
```

You can then call this method by doing

```
decimal rate = someCalculationDetailsCollection.GetTheThing(x => x.Rate, 0, "category0")
```

This would be similar to just using LINQ directly:

```
someCalculationDetailsCollection
    .Where(x => x.Id == 0 && x.Category == "category0")
    .Select(x => x.Rate)
```

Comment: Can you please tell how it will work, I mean propertyExtractor(matchingCalculationDetails)? I am not able to relate it with the LINQ query mentioned above.

Comment: Also, I don't think this will handle null collection.

Comment: `x => x.Rate` is a method that takes as its argument a CalculationDetails x and returns x.Rate.
So if you say `Func<CalculationDetails> myLambdaMethod = x => x.Rate` you can do `myLambdaMethod(new CalculationDetails { Rate = 22 })` and the result will be 22.

Comment: It is correct that it won't handle empty/null collections. That along with correct matching logic is left for the developer who knows better the requirements of the specific case.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do what you asked for:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static object GetCalculationDetailsValue(this ICollection<CalculationDetails> freightCalculationDetails, string propertyName, int calculationId, string category)
    {
        var calculationDetails = freightCalculationDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == calculationId && x.Category == category);

        if(calculationDetails is null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return typeof(CalculationDetails).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(calculationDetails);
    }
}

public class CalculationDetails
{
    public int Id;
    public decimal? Rate;
    public decimal? Amount;
    public int ChargeId;
    public string Category;
    public int UnitId;
}
```

Anyway you should avoid that kind of approach, it uses reflection which is really slow and avoidable in most situations.